# I need to fade the sound samples on a file to zero gradually

Tags: python, jython, jes

Hi i need help writing this code in `Jes`?

Gradually fades the sound samples to zero. Each sample is reduced by a different percentage. The percentage depends on its position in the file.

The first sample is not changed. The sample which is a quarter way through the file is reduced by 25%. The sample at the half way point is reduced by 50%. The last sample is reduced by 100%.

```
def fade(sound):
  for index in range(0,getLength(sound),1):
    ratio = (1-index/getLength(sound))
    setSampleValueAt(sound, index, getSampleValueAt(sound, index)*ratio)
```

This is what i did but i don't know what I am doing wrong.  Please help.:)